# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound sound volume dependency

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm making iOS keyboard extension.

To play click sound, I used `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`.

However some users reported that the click sound sometimes depends on 'bell sound volume(bell icon)' and sometimes 'normal sound volume(speaker icon)'

I tested on Apple memo app and found there are cases about inconstant dependency.

Here is my code to init

```
func initTypeSound(soundIndex: Int) {
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    for var i = 0 ; i < MAX_TYPE_SOUND_COUNT ; i++ {
        if let url = bundle.URLForResource(NSString(format: "type%d_%d", soundIndex, i) as String, withExtension: "wav") {
            // file exist
            var soundID : SystemSoundID = 0
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &soundID)
            mTypeSoundIDs.insert(soundID, atIndex: i)
        } else {
            // no file
        }
    }
}
```

and code to play

```
func play(soundType: KKSoundType) {
    if (!mHasPermission || !mIsSound) {
        return
    }

    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let systemVolumn = session.outputVolume
    if (systemVolumn == 0) {
        return
    }

    var soundId : SystemSoundID!
    switch (soundType) {
    case .Type:
        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(mTypeSoundIDs.count)));
        soundId = mTypeSoundIDs[rand];
        break
    case .Space:
        soundId = mSpaceSoundID;
        break
    default:
        return
    }
    if mIsSound {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
    }
}
```